# Need better maintainability for long tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been using the HTML `title` attr + *jquery-cluetip* plugin for tooltips. Occasionally, however, I have tooltips that contain several sentences and that would lead to long `title` attr and html tag. This conflicts with my coding style. For better maintainability, I tend to organize my code to avoid as much horizontal scrolling as possible.

Please advise other approaches for dealing with long tooltip.

Answer (score 2):

One way that I have done it is add a span tag with a class of tooltip.  The on the hover of the parent element you can make it show.  One nice thing is it can be done all in CSS and formatting is usually simpler.

Here is a link to an earlier answer that gives an example of what I'm talking about.  Here there are two span tags.  One to act as link and the other as the tooltip.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4441477/379650

Comment: Any concerns with this pure CSS approach over using javascript that I should be aware of?

Comment: Except for the fact that you have a few extra HTML elements none that I'm aware of (I know that some don't always like adding extra HTML and obviously with javascript you could add the HTML after page load or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with horizontal scrolling? Scrolling in the code or scrolling in the browser?

If you meant horizontal browser scroll you can fix that with `max-width`

Comment: Just hit "enter" when you think you've reached you limit... You can also use your editors "Word Wrap" options